# php upload: zip files

Tags: php, file-upload, php-5.3, zip

Why can't I get the .zip as type and its size through an uploading form but only can get its name only?

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => attachments_2011_05_20.zip
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Something extra should I do to get the zip size and type?

Comment: Additional to the answers below: the data provided in `$_FILES` also depends on what the client sends. [Better to check the file-type on the server, using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457797/best-way-to-recognize-a-filetype-in-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [error code](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) is `1`, which means means "file is too large" - your [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) setting is too low, so the upload is being aborted.

Comment: Thanks. I have increased the size of `upload_max_filesize` and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

LIST OF ERROR CODES
UPLOAD_ERR_OK

Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success. 
UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE

**Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. 
UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE**

Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form. 
UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL

Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially uploaded. 
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE

Value: 4; No file was uploaded. 
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR

Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3. 
UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE

Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0. 
UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION

Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with phpinfo() may help. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php